# Is there any way of stopping cloth collision jittering all over the place?

Tags: cloth-simulation

I've researched and tweaked the parameters as best as I could and the collision is much better, but there is no way when I collide a collider object over a cloth it will stop jittering and twitching.

The cloth in question is attached to an armature with only the border vertices pinnined, is also receiving pressure from cloth parameters, also, Idk if it's important but, the cloth is all closed, it's a convex mesh. The thickness from both the cloth and the collider are at the minimum (0.001); the dynamic properties are from rubber preset. I've turn all the way up impulse clamping as well.

So, is there a way of stopping the collision glitching when I lay something upon the cloth please?

Comment: You could try to enable the Self Collision (not sure if that will help tough), And turn up the collision steps under the cloth settings to something like 10 to 20

Comment: I've done this already =(